# Android - 360 video metadata

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, metadata, 360-virtual-reality

So with ffmpeg I've concatenated two 360 videos into one. The problem is that I lost all the 360 video metadata in the final video (so it's not recognized as a 360 video anymore). If I use exiftool on the final video, I lack those metadatas :

- Spherical                       : true
- Stitched                        : true
- Stitching Software              : Spherical Metadata Tool
- Projection Type                 : equirectangular

I've tried to inject those metadatas with ffmpeg, like this for example :

```
ffmpeg -i <input_video> -metadata Spherical="true" -codec copy <output_video>
```

I don't get any errors doing that, but exiftool still doesn't show the metadatas.

I know Google has a Python script that does this well, [here](https://github.com/google/spatial-media) .

But I would like to inject metadatas in my app as well, any help would be much appreciated,

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it using mp4 parser :

[mp4 parser (github)](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser)

Comment: How you managed it?

because after I cropped video I will lose my 360 metadata so how can I prevent from this